# What is the name of something that possesses a desire?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the name of an object that possesses a desire?

As examples, all humans possess desires. More generally, sentient beings possess desires. However, we can up the abstraction. Organizations possess desires. States possess desires.

What is the name of an entity that possesses desires?

Comment: An entity with desires would not be an 'object'. The entity will have a personality in order to be able to have desires. It will be a person. Animals have instincts. It is debatable that instincts can be called 'desires' in the way that humans have desires. Humans also have instincts, of course, in common with animals. It is also debatable to say that animals have 'personalities' in the same way that humans have.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I chose the wrong word. By 'object,' I just mean 'thing.' I'm using object in the broadest sense possible. By my definition, a human being is an object.

Comment: I think that neither the English language nor the Courts of the Judiciary agree with you, there. A corpse is an 'object'. A living human is a person.

Comment: @NigelJ Never mind. What is it that can have a desire? is the Q at hand, anyway.

Comment: extremeaxe, There's a reason those entities are called "bodies" -- they possess and/or exhibit features of living organisms -- desire being just one of them.

Comment: @Kris Is an 'organism' a 'person' ?

Comment: @NigelJ An organism, not necessarily a person, for that context.

Comment: @Kris A corporation can be an entity - the Inland Revenue told me so. But a corporation is not a person. Can a corporation have a desire ?

Comment: @NigelJ Sure, inasmuch as it's a body corporate. *"The board has elected you president of the university and we are here to notify you. It is the board's desire that you accept."* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troy_H._Middleton#cite_ref-Price,_306_164-1

Comment: It is unclear what you are looking for. Are you trying to fill a slot in a sentence, and the syntax for that slot requires it to be a single word? Or are you philosophizing and wondering what the label should be in the abstract relation of 'X desires Y', analagous to, say, an employer employs an employee?

Comment: It’s sad that extremeaxe5 used sloppy terms like “something” and “object“, let alone tried to lay down “By my definition, a human being is an object” but who seriously doubts what was meant by “humans” then “sentient beings”?

It’s sad that extremeaxe5 used sloppy terms like “something” and “object“, let alone tried to lay down “By my definition, a human being is an object” but who seriously doubts what was meant by “humans” then “sentient beings”? It might be worth doubting whether “possesses” mattered, as opposed to “has” or “formulates” or even, for instance “follows up.”

Comment: What’s being asked doesn’t mean there’s an answer.

Broadly, desires are possessed by “creatures”, to me meaning roughly “animals” and not minerals or vegetables.

Then it becomes too tenuous. Is the suitor for Miss Valentine’s heart to be compared with the highwayman hoping to plunder pilgrims’ pockets or the gambler watching for the card so high and wild he'll never need to deal another?

Doesn’t the nature of the desire make as much difference?

Comment: @NigelJ can you provide some evidence of this claim? I was under the impression that ‘object’ is in fact a very specific word that refers to the class of everything in the universe of discourse. Humans are organisms, which are physical objects, which are objects. Sets are objects. Groups are monoids are sets are objects. Sets and humans are very different, one being physical, and he other being abstract, but they are both objects. If you reserve the word ‘object’ to refer to inanimate, physical objects, then what word do you use to refer to the class of all possible things?

Comment: @Mitch I am asking for the latter. What is the label assigned to the class of objects, whose members are precisely those objects possessing desires.

Comment: @extremeaxe5 Every 'thing' in creation is made of atoms. But that which is immaterial is not made of atoms and is not a 'thing'.

Comment: @NigelJ Is an abstract concept a thing? Is the number 2 a thing? Check dictionary definitions and you'll find that 'thing' is often used for immaterial things. I agree with you that the canonical use of 'thing' has a slight connotation that is more ... let's say corporeal than entity. But look at all the non-corporeal uses of things in those definitions.

Comment: @Mitch Abstract concepts, I agree, can still be 'things'. But the immaterial existence that is a person - is not, to my mind - a 'thing'. Definitely Person. There are people desperately trying to prove that Person is a feature of quantum fluctuation but I believe - very firmly - they would be better employed doing something else.

Comment: I something that had "purpose" might be said to have "agency" although "agent" might not be right.. 'a factor' might be better. However that is more about "active asserting a purpose" than "desire".  An "**interested party**" might get there?

Comment: @NigelJ ok. What word do you use to refer to the class of everything possible in the universe of discourse?

Answer (score 2):

Relations are made of three concepts, a subject, the relation, and an object.

For example, in an employment relation, there is an employer (the one offering the job) and the employee (the one doing the work).

If you want to label the three items in a relation 'X is related to Y' which is specific to the relation 'desires', then that is very easy. Based on the 'employs' example, the subject would be

> the desirer

and object

> the desired.

But that sounds infelicitous, very formal and technical; 'desirer' is formed according to legal word formation rules in English but it is not a common term (it's not a common concept). It would totally work in a philosophical exposition,  but not going out for a smoke behind the fast food joint.

Which is all to say there is no *natural* sounding term for the subject of desire, unlike 'employer' which works so well for its relation.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you're going to find a noun for this. But if you assume that desires always have objects, then an adjective could be **goal oriented**.

In other words, the goal of any such object is to meet a certain goal (to acquire the object of its "desire").

In such a sense, a baby is goal oriented toward getting food, and a business is goal oriented toward maximizing profit.

Although I don't normally supply Wikipedia references, [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Very_high-level_programming_language) is something on programming languages. The emphasis is mine.

> Very high-level programming languages are usually domain-specific languages, limited to a very specific application, purpose, or type of task, and they are often scripting languages (especially extension languages), controlling a specific environment. For this reason, very high-level programming languages are often referred to as **goal-oriented** programming languages.

The idea of [goal modelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goal_modeling) is also related. Here, as it applies to businesses.

In a reverse sense, then, anything that has a purpose (or function or goal) has a "desire" for those things that fulfill its purpose.